# MongoDB Aggregate by subgroup already group by Date

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a mongo collection which contains Projects and represented like this (small sample):

```
{
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5c615f9141d6ec562be9fd4d"),
        "title" : "Project1",
        "_created" : ISODate("2019-02-11T11:42:09Z"),
        "org" : [
            "ORG1"
        ]
    }
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5cf4ec11362a5f02b74effd3"),
        "title" : "Project2",
        "org" : [
            "ORG2"
        ],
        "_created" : ISODate("2018-06-03T09:44:49Z")
    }
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5d0362eb362a5f488a315508"),
        "title" : "Another Project",
        "org" : [
            "ORG3"
        ],
        "_created" : ISODate("2019-06-14T09:03:39Z")
    }
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5d0362eb362a5f488a315508"),
        "title" : "Multi Org Project",
        "org" : [
            "ORG1",
            "ORG3"
        ],
        "_created" : ISODate("2018-06-14T09:03:39Z")
    }
}
```

What I would like to do is to known by a time interval (e.g $day/$month/$year) the number of project created in each organisation (org).

I am struggling at doing that in a mongo aggregation.

I succeed to do this :

- Counting the number of projects created by year

```
db.projects.aggregate({$group:{_id:{$year: "$_created"}, project:{$sum:1}}})
```

- Counting the projects created by Org

```
db.projects.aggregate([{$unwind:"$org"}, {$group:{_id: "$org", project: {$sum:1}}}])
```

But how combinate both ? I don't want to force any results format but he would be something like :

```
{
    2017: {
        "ORG1": 12,
        "ORG2": 3,
    },
    2018...
}
```

I found lot of question about MongoDB Aggragation Framework but I still don't get it.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

unwind your org array, then group twice to achieve this :

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $unwind: "$org"
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        year: {
          $year: "$_created"
        },
        org: "$org"
      },
      count: {
        $sum: 1
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$_id.year",
      res: {
        $addToSet: {
          org: "$_id.org",
          count: "$count"
        }
      }
    }
  },
])
```

WIll output

```
[
  {
    "_id": 2018,
    "res": [
      {
        "count": 1,
        "org": "ORG1"
      },
      {
        "count": 1,
        "org": "ORG3"
      },
      {
        "count": 2,
        "org": "ORG2"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "_id": 2019,
    "res": [
      {
        "count": 1,
        "org": "ORG2"
      },
      {
        "count": 1,
        "org": "ORG1"
      },
      {
        "count": 1,
        "org": "ORG3"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

You can add further stages to reshape your documents if needed.

[Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/V6God770vzV)

Comment: It works ! Also tried like this :
`db.projects.aggregate([{$match: {"_deleted": false, "org": {$exists: true}}}, {$unwind: "$org"}, {$group:{_id:{$year: "$_created"}, projectsList:{$push: "$org"}}}])`  But have the same problem to group after.

Comment: the trick is to group first with both year and org, then group by year.